# Python / Django - How to create regex (RegexValidator) which allows only letters and spaces?

Tags: python, regex, django

This is my code:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    alphaSpaces = RegexValidator(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$', 'Only letters and spaces are allowed in the Location Name.')


    locationName = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True, validators=[alphaSpaces])
```

But when I try to create a location called 'Location My Location' it raises the error and says `Only letters and spaces are allowed in the Location Name`.

For what it's worth, I am using a RESTful API and passing the location name in a JSON object like this:

```
data = {'locationName': 'Location My Location'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you also want spaces to be allowed too, your regex should be:
`'^[a-zA-Z ]+$'`

Comment: Edit: Thanks, worked. Looks like I forgot the space after the Z in the regex.

Comment: @lambo477 Yea just saw it. I'll mark this answer off when I can (in 10 minutes).